# Auto-Dump Files genereted?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL in which the auto-generating of many dump file stored on the log file, and it cause a problem in my internal storage.

Please if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have enabled the InnoDB Monitor, which outputs statistics and reports to the error log file every 15 seconds.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-enabling-monitors.html

Disable the monitors with these statements:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_status_output=OFF;
SET GLOBAL innodb_status_output_locks=OFF;
```

In older versions of MySQL, instead of configuration options, they used an [odd way of enabling the monitor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-enabling-monitors.html). It was to create a table in the InnoDB engine named `innodb_monitor` or `innodb_lock_monitor` or `innodb_tablespace_monitor`. It didn't matter what columns were in this table or which schema you created it in. The existence of a table by those names would start the monitor output to the logs. You need to use either DROP TABLE or RENAME TABLE for each of those to disable the monitor output.

In addition, you should configure your MySQL Server to do log rotation, so the error log never fills the storage. There are many blogs describing how to do this, here's one example: https://scalegrid.io/blog/managing-mysql-server-logs-rotate-compress-retain-delete/